# Heroku git bash won't open browser for login

Tags: heroku, git-bash

When I try to log in on git bash it says "*heroku: Press any key to open up the browser to login or q to exit:*". I am pressing it, but it's stuck here. It wont open browser for login.

Comment: This has nothing to do with Git (and in the end, little to do with git-bash, which is just a port of bash to Windows, included *with* Git because Git on Windows *uses* bash, but at least the [tag:git-bash] tag is justifiable here since you're launching things from git-bash).

Answer (score 1):

Looks like there is an incident with heroku login! Facing the same issue. Cannot login via the dashboard too.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

Have you reset your password yet? They just force reset all passwords that hadn't been updated since a recent breech occurred. I was unable to login this morning and found all my sessions had expired. Once I did the password reset I was able to login again as normal.

**Details**

> Salesforce-owned subsidiary Heroku on Thursday acknowledged that the
> theft of GitHub integration OAuth tokens further involved unauthorized
> access to an internal customer database.
>
> The company, in an updated notification, revealed that a compromised
> token was abused to breach the database and "exfiltrate the hashed and
> salted passwords for customers' user accounts."
>
> As a consequence, Salesforce said it's resetting all Heroku user
> passwords and ensuring that potentially affected credentials are
> refreshed. It also emphasized that internal Heroku credentials were
> rotated and extra detections have been put in place.

- **Official**: https://status.heroku.com/incidents/2413
- **Press**: https://thehackernews.com/2022/05/heroku-forces-user-password-resets.html